# SSH Public Key Format

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-keys, public-key

I have a public key in the format:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----

Comment: "somename-20060227"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBmhLUTJiP[and so on]==

---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Usually I see keys in the format like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAqof[and so on]
```

Can I just copy the first key in the authorized_keys file or do I have to modify it somehow so it looks like the second one? I think the first one was generated by PUTTYgen while the second one was generated by ssh-keygen.

Comment: Puttygen generates _both_. On Windows the GUI box cleverly labeled "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys" is the OpenSSH format, but the _button_ SavePublicKey or the equivalent item in the File menu gives the RFC4716/Tectia format. On Unix you specify `-O public-openssh` or `-O public`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use `ssh-keygen -i` to convert SSH2-compatible format to OpenSSH compatible format.

from `man ssh-keygen`:

> -i       This option will read an unencrypted private (or public) key
> file in SSH2-compatible format and print an OpenSSH compatible private
> (or public) key to stdout.  ssh-keygen also reads the RFC 4716 SSH
> Public Key File Format.  This option allows importing keys from several commercial SSH implementations.

&

> ```
> -f filename
>         Specifies the filename of the key file.
> ```

example:

> ssh-keygen -i -f ssh2.pub

Answer (score 11):

This is the complete, correct answer:

`ssh-keygen -i -m PKCS8 -f public-key.pem`

Comment: "RFC4716" is the default key_format, and -m does appear to be for specifying the format of the INPUT in this instance, not the output, so you are correct.

Comment: Technically alexus' "correct" answer is NOT wrong though, as that answer is not spelling out full syntax - only pointing to which primary flag should be used, leaving the need to check -i syntax/usage in the man page.

Answer (score 4):

You do have to convert the public key to openssh convention:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIBmhLUTJiP[and so on]== somename-20060227
```

Also make sure that the key occupies exactly one line and no line breaks were introduced while copying.

Answer (score 3):

Just rewrite your key in format suited for `authorized_keys`:

keytype keybody keyname

Keep in mind that trailing "==" are necessary placeholders to keep keylength equal to desired length.

Comment: The trailing "==" are [Base64 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding)

Comment: how do I know if its RSA or DSA?

Answer (score 0):

To create public keys for a number of password encrypted private keys the following script will:

1. Read the private key with `ssh-keygen -e` and output a public key - and ask for the private key password
2. Create a PEM based public key and store in an environment variable
3. Use `ssh-keygen -i` to create and OpenSSH compatible public key
4. And write to a `.pub` output file

```bash
for i in $(ls -1 id_rsa_* | grep -v "\.pub$")  # Ignore .pub files
do
  PEM=$(ssh-keygen -e -f $i -m PEM)  # Will ask for the private key password
  echo $(ssh-keygen -i -m PEM -f <(echo "$PEM")) KEY-ALIAS > $i.pub
done
```

A side note, `seahorse`, the Ubuntu "Passwords and keys" agent, **requires** the public keys to be able to store the private keys.